# Aggregation into mean, min and max of a List of Dictionaries using Python 3.7 and not using pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following data

```
data = [{'item': 'A', 'price': '$52'},
{'item': 'B', 'price': '$21'},
{'item': 'C', 'price': '$35'},
{'item': 'A', 'price': '$52'},
{'item': 'A', 'price': '$52'},
{'item': 'B', 'price': '$21'}]
```

How do I aggregate item A, B and C this without using pandas and only python 3+
Appreciate any links to help me out here.

Expected output is

```
A $156
B $42
C $35
```

I have tried the following code:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_data, lambda item: item['item']):
    print(key, sum([item["item"] for item in group]))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Are there any simpler solutions to this:

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {"item": "A", "price": "$52"},
    {"item": "B", "price": "$21"},
    {"item": "C", "price": "$35"},
    {"item": "A", "price": "$52"},
    {"item": "A", "price": "$52"},
    {"item": "B", "price": "$21"},
]

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    result[d["item"]].append(d["price"])

result = {key: f"${sum(int(v[1:]) for v in value)}" for key, value in result.items()}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'A': '$156', 'B': '$42', 'C': '$35'}
```

Comment: Vishal bhai, great code.... This helps me understand the code much better

Answer (score -1):

1. You are trying to sum `item`, instead of `price`.
2. `price` is a string starting with `'$'` so you can't expect `sum` to magically handle it (ie, remove `'$'`, sum the rest as numbers then prepend `'$'` when it's done).

The easiest solution will be to manually strip off the first character of `price`, use `sum` then prepend the `$` again when printing.

```
def key_func(d):
    return d['item']

for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=key_func), key=key_func):
    print(key, '$' + str(sum(int(item['price'].lstrip('$')) for item in group)))
```

outputs

```
A $156
B $42
C $35
```

Comment: Why is this code so complicated. Is there a simpler step by step approach to this..

Comment: @JohnDoe You can break `str(sum(int(item['price'].lstrip('$')) for item in group))` to as many steps as you would like. I already explained in point 2 why a naive use of `sum` does not work.